# How to retain state of a variable when dealing with asynchronous functions and their callbacks?

Tags: node.js

If I read a directory and then I wanted to cycle through those files and tell what is a directory with the path file name. How would you keep track of that file variable that? Or should I just be using the sync version?

Here's example code:

```
fs.readdir("../directory", function(err, files) {
    if(err) throw err;

    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        fs.stat(files[i], function(err, stats) {
            //files[i] will be files[ files.length - 1 ] when the callback is called
            console.log("%s %s", files[i], stats.isDirectory())
        });
    }

});
```

It would be cool if you could pass in your own variables to fs.stat, like after the callback.

Comment: You could use bind on your callback function to pass in the file in question as an extra parameter.

Comment: Ahh! Wonderful. Man I feel silly for not doing that in the first place. Thanks Thilo!